# Continuing logarithm $\log(\log(\dots\log(z)))$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms

I don't know the best way to describe it in technical terms, but what is the result of a continuing logarithm of $z$, for example:

$$\log(\log(\dots\log(z)))$$

Where it is taking the logarithm of the logarithm and so on, for an infinite amount of times?

**How would this type of thing behave?** Does it converge, go off to infinity or an infinitesimal? Does the resulting behavior depend on whether $z$ is imaginary or real? Positive or negative?

Comment: The term you are looking for is "composition." We call $f(g(z))$ the composition of $f$ and $g$ and I would describe this as "the limit of repetitive self-compositions"

Comment: @StellaBiderman Better: Iteration.  An iteration is repeated compositions of the same function.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt haha. I almost wrote "iterated composition." Good to know that's a Thing.

Comment: Proposal to merge this with my old question I found: [Does logging infinitely converge?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1587350/does-logging-infinitely-converge)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\Im(z)$ (the imaginary part of $z$) is greater than or equal to zero, then this converges to roughly $z_\infty = 0.318152 + 1.33724 i$.

If $\Im(z)<0$ it converges to  $z_\infty = 0.318152 - 1.33724 i$.

This of course relies on the usual branch cut for $\log z$.

The exceptional cases are any cases where a finite number of itetations lands on $1$ (or starting with $z=0$.  These include $1, e, e^e$, and so forth.

However, there are isolated points for which the iterated log neither goes to infinity nor converges.  For example, for any $z$ such that  $$e^z = \log z \neq z$$
the iterated log oscillates between $z$ and $\log z$. I think there are such points; for example, there is an unstable 2-cycle fixed point at roughly
$$
z= 0.883998 + 6.922346 i
$$

Comment: Lol, I too find proving convergence a hard task.

Comment: The branch choice should rule out such points. For example your example cannot have this property since $\Im \log(z) \in (-\pi,\pi]$ so $\log(\log(z)) \not= z$ since $\Im z = 6.92 > \pi$.

Comment: @Winther You are right, my example point does not work.  I'll have to see where I went wrong.

Comment: @Winther WHenever I zero in an apparent fixed point, the second iteration comes out off by $2\pi i$, which I take as a sign that branch cuts are preventing it from happening.  For example, $$\log(\log(0.883998+6.92275i))\approx 0.883998+6.92275i-2\pi i$$

Comment: Exactly. That happens since we are working with a fixed branch of the logarithm which constrains the imaginary part to be in a certain band. The equation $e^z = \log(z)$ do have infinitely many solutions, however only two of them have an imaginary part corresponding to any particular branch choice $\text{Log}(z)$ so if $\text{Log}(\text{Log}(z)) = z$ then $\text{Log}(z) = z$ which equals one of the two fixpoints it can converge to. I think the only way we can have cycles is if we could make a different branch choice for the logarithm at each step (for which we can make any sequence diverge).

Answer (score 1):

***Iff*** it converges, then

$$a=\log(\log(\dots\log(z)\dots))=\log(a)$$

Thus,

$$a=\log(a)$$

$$e^a=a\implies-1=-ae^{-a}\implies a=-W_k(-1)\stackrel{k=0}\approx0.318-1.337i$$

is the Lambert W function.  Note that this is constant, and dependent only on whether or not the choice of $z$ converge and where $z$ is.  The position of $z$ will determine which branch of the Lambert W function it will converge to.  A couple notes:

If we $z$ is a perfect super power of $e$, then it diverges due to $\log(0)$. That is, $z\ne e^{e^{e^{\dots}}}$ and $z\ne0$.

I am pretty sure it converges everywhere else, with the exception of $z=-W(-1)$.

Not finished with the rest:
$\color{white}{Let \$z=re^{i\theta}\$.  Then we have
\$\$\log(z)=\log(r)+i\theta=r_1e^{i\theta_1}\$\$
We can see that \$r_1=\sqrt{\log^2(r)+\theta^2}\$ and \$\theta_1=\arg(\log(r)+i\theta)\$.  From this, we can discern that \$r\$ must be bounded, and likewise, we are left to look at $\theta$.  As \$r\to r'\$ be the limit of \$r\$, \$\theta\$ also approaches a limit}$

Comment: "I am pretty sure it diverges everywhere else though" Why is that?

Comment: @Winther Memory, because I think I asked a similar question before.

Comment: That's not a very convincing argument.

Comment: @Winther Of course not.  Give me a few minutes here.

Comment: A big big issue is the domain of definition... for example, $x$ has already to be above 15 or so for $ln(ln(ln(ln(x))))$ to be defined... (I prefer to work with normalized notation "ln").

Comment: @JeanMarie Was just following notation.  And note that domain shouldn't be a problem, the OP's tags and words like "complex" and "imaginary" in the main post should tell you this.

Comment: A small numerical experiment shows that it converges for all input not on the form $1,e,e^e,\ldots$. This is using the principal branch.

Comment: @Winther Ah, thanks....

Comment: There are infinitely many $z$ with $e^z = z$.

Comment: @DanielFischer :-) Goodness, I'm still editing from my comment almost 15 minutes ago XD

Comment: @Winther I wouldn't be fully trustful towards numerical experiments. I would have bet that "the" or a "a" branch cut has to be continuous, for example $(-\infty, e]$.

Comment: @JeanMarie There is nothing magical happening here. Taking a logarithm under a given branch is a well defined operation which is easy to compute. There is no rational reason to not trust such numerical experiments. Of course one cannot cover *all* cases this way, but it gives the general behavior.

Comment: :( Sadly, I only know how to prove convergence here with limits and bounded/monotone arguments.  Does anyone have better ideas?

Comment: The iterated log does **not** converge for **all** complex $z$ not of the form $0,1,e,e^3,\ldots$.  See my answer for an example $z$ that causes the iterated log to oscillate in a 2-cycle.  But this is an unstable point, so it is almost surely true that the iterated log converges everywhere except for a set of measure zero.

Comment: @MarkFischler Very interesting.  I imagine we could try to look for n-cycles, but they seem hard to find.