# Ways to re-write/simplify the logarithm of a logartihm etc, for example $\log(\log(\log(\log(x))))$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, logarithms

I have been unable to find an answer to how to simplify or rewrite the expression when taking multiple logarithms, i.e. is there a more compact way to write $\log(\log(x))$ or for that matter $\log(\log(\log(\log(x))))$, while still using logarithms in the more compact expression?

And is there a formula to generalize it for any case of an arbitrary number of logs, for example taking 5 $log$'s, i.e. $\log(\log(\log(\log(\log(x)))))$, we could rewrite this as ... ?

Please note I am not looking for the limit as the number of $\log$'s go to infinity, as is resolved in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2124782/continuing-logarithm-log-log-dots-logz) or in [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1587350/does-logging-infinitely-converge).

EDIT: I need this to be able to compute the $y$, in $y=\log(\log(\log(...\log(x))))$

Comment: Iterated function?

Comment: Used wikipedia to look it up, but not really what I'm looking for if I understand it correctly

Comment: you could write it as a tower of $e$

Comment: So for $log(log(log(log(x))))$, how would you re-write it? please show

Comment: Then you can simply define it. Say $^3\log(x)=\log(\log(\log(x)))$.

Comment: ok, but I also have to be able to use the expression in doing calculations, or in MATLAB/R etc, so just changing the notation is of little use to me...

Comment: Then put that in the question.

Comment: @JefferyOpoku-Mensah yes, good idea!

Comment: If you're concerned about programming it, I think this is a more appropriate question for StackOverflow. In `R`, you could do something like `log_iter <- function(n, x){for (i in 1:n){x <- log(x)}; return(x)}`

Comment: There is no shorter way to write $\log(\log(\log(\log x)))$ using elementary functions.

Comment: not sure if this helps but point to be noted is that your nested logarithm does not converge if $x$ is of the form $1,e^e,e^{e^e}\cdots$

Comment: Using a different notation to the original is not going to help you to compute $y$, since any new notation is simply notation. If you want to compute it use something like (Java) e.g. `double itlog(int value, int depth) { if(depth == 5) return value; else return itlog(log(value), depth+1); }`

Comment: People usually write $\log^n x$ for $\underbrace{\log\log\cdots\log}_{\text{$n$ times}}\,x$. @Antinous "if (depth == 5)"??

Comment: @Rahul You can change `depth==5` to `==6` `==7`, or whatever is required, e.g. `==n` where `n` is some global variable, or some parameter you also pass in to the function if you prefer. (I did say "use something like," not to be taken literally)

Comment: Iterated logarithms are used quite a bit in analytic number theory (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Lower_bounds), for example), so this is one place to look if you want to see how people express such things. Most of the time they just write out the logarithm composition (it's usually at most 4), although I've also seen subscripts and superscripts used (the latter sometimes written as ${\log}^{[4]},$ to distinguish from exponentiation).

Comment: Quoting [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) "To avoid ambiguity, some mathematicians choose to write $f^{\circ n}$ for the $n$-th iterate of the function $f$". So $\log(\log(\log(\log(x))))$ can be shortened to $\log^{\circ 4}(x)$. As long as you define this before its use, everything will be fine.

Comment: To compute $y$, you either need a CAS that knows how to do function iterate or write a code to do the iteration yourself. On [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Nest[Log,3814280,5]), you can use the Nest command for function iterate. e.g. `Nest[Log,3814280,5]` gives you $\log^{\circ 5}(3814280) \approx -18.9832$  (3814280 is the smallest integer $n$ where $\log^{\circ 5}(n)$ is real).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider the function
$$f(x) = \log^{(5)}x = \log(\log(\log(\log(\log(x))))).$$
This function takes real values [when](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5Ee%5Ee)
$$x\ge e_3 = e^{e^e},$$
where
$$e_{_0} = 1,\quad e_{_{k+1}} = e^{e_k}.$$
Derivatives of $f(x)$ are
\begin{align}
&f'(x) = \dfrac{1}{x\log(x)\log^{(2)}(x)\log^{(3)}(x)\log^{(4)}(x)},\\
&\log f'(x) = - \log(x) - \log^{(2)}(x) - \log^{(3)}(x) - \log^{(4)}(x) - \log^{(5)}(x),\\
&f''(x) = -f'(x)\Bigg(\dfrac1x + \dfrac{1}{x\log(x)} + \dfrac{1}{x\log(x)\log^{(2)}(x)} + \dfrac{1}{x\log(x)\log^{(2)}(x)\log^{(3)}(x)}\\
& + \dfrac{1}{x\log(x)\log^{(2)}(x)\log^{(3)}(x)\log^{(4)}(x)}\Bigg),\\
&f'''(x) = -f''(x)\Bigg(\dfrac1x + \dfrac{1}{x\log(x)} + \dfrac{1}{x\log(x)\log^{(2)}(x)} + \dfrac{1}{x\log(x)\log^{(2)}(x)\log^{(3)}(x)}\\
& + \dfrac{1}{x\log(x)\log^{(2)}(x)\log^{(3)}(x)\log^{(4)}(x)}\Bigg)\\
&+f'(x)\Bigg(\dfrac1{x^2} + \dfrac{1}{x\log(x)}\left(\dfrac1x+\dfrac1{x\log x}\right)\\
& + \dfrac{1}{x\log(x)\log^{(2)}(x)}\left(\dfrac1x+\dfrac1{x\log x}+\dfrac{1}{x\log(x)\log^{(2)}(x)}\right)\\
& + \dfrac{1}{x\log(x)\log^{(2)}(x)\log^{(3)}(x)}\\
&\times\left(\dfrac1x+\dfrac1{x\log x}+\dfrac{1}{x\log(x)\log^{(2)}(x)} + \dfrac{1}{x\log(x)\log^{(2)}(x)\log^{(3)}(x)}\right)\\
& + \dfrac{1}{x\log(x)\log^{(2)}(x)\log^{(3)}(x)\log^{(4)}(x)}\Bigg(\dfrac1x + \dfrac{1}{x\log(x)} + \dfrac{1}{x\log(x)\log^{(2)}(x)} + \dfrac{1}{x\log(x)\log^{(2)}(x)\log^{(3)}(x)} + \dfrac{1}{x\log(x)\log^{(2)}(x)\log^{(3)}(x)\log^{(4)}(x)}\Bigg)\Bigg),\\
&f'''(x) = \dfrac{f''^2(x)}{f'(x)} - f''(x)+f'(x)\Bigg(\dfrac1{x^2} + \dfrac{1}{x\log(x)}\left(\dfrac1x+\dfrac1{x\log x}\right)\\
& + \dfrac{1}{x\log(x)\log^{(2)}(x)}\left(\dfrac1x+\dfrac1{x\log x}+\dfrac{1}{x\log(x)\log^{(2)}(x)}\right)\\
& + \dfrac{1}{x\log(x)\log^{(2)}(x)\log^{(3)}(x)}\\
&\times\left(\dfrac1x+\dfrac1{x\log x}+\dfrac{1}{x\log(x)\log^{(2)}(x)} + \dfrac{1}{x\log(x)\log^{(2)}(x)\log^{(3)}(x)}\right)\Bigg)\dots
\end{align}
The value and the derivatives [in the point](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5Ee%5Ee%5Ee%5Ee) $e_5$ are
\begin{align}
&f(e_5) = 1,\\
&f'(e_5) = e^{-\left(e_4+e_3+e_2+e+1\right)},\\
&f''(e_5) = -e^{-2\left(e_4+e_3+e_2+e+1\right)}\left(e_4e_3e_2e+e_3e_2e+e_2e+e+1\right),\\
&f'''(e_5) =e^{-3\left(e_4+e_3+e_2+e+1\right)}\left(e_4e_3e_2e+e_3e_2e+e_2e+e+1\right)^2\\
&+e^{-2\left(e_4+e_3+e_2+e+1\right)}\left(e_4e_3e_2e+e_3e_2e+e_2e+e+1\right)\\
&e^{-\left(e_4+e_3+e_2+e+1\right)}\left(e^{-2e_4}+e^{-2\left(e_4+e_3\right)}(e_4+1)+e^{-2\left(e_4+e_3+e_2\right)}(e_4e_3+e_3+1)+e^{-2\left(e_4+e_3+e_2+2\right)}(e_4e_3e_2+e_3e_2+e_2+1)+\right)\dots\\
&f(x)=f(e_5)+f'(e_5)(x-e_5)+\dfrac1{2!}f"(e_5)(x-e_5)^2+\dfrac1{3!}f'''(e_5)(x-e_5)^3+\dots
\end{align}
The standard procedure considered allows us to construct a Taylor series at an arbitrary point. At the same time, the usefulness of this series raises great doubts.

More useful looks a function of the form
$$\log(1+\log(1+\log(1+\log(1+\log(1+x))))),$$
which is defined for $x\ge0.$

Comment: Thanks for the taylor approximation, although it's less exact than I had in mind, and I totally agree with you regarding its limited usefulness, so I guess the conclusion is that this approximation is the only way to approach it (other than writing out log(log...etc))? Also, thanks for the side note of log(1+log(...)).

Comment: @litmus You are welcome! At first, I wanted to show the technic of Taylor series calculations in the given case (its complexity was a challenge for me too), as logarthmic derivative and recurrency. At the second, all elements of this technic can be used for the other proposed function, which seems more perspectve. The proposed function is quite often found in practice, and in particular - when evaluating the performance of algorithms. Therefore, I hope that the potential of the issue question is sufficiently disclosed in my answer.